# Adicionar evento no FullCalendar de forma dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Eu tenho uma lista de professores, dentro de cada professor, tenho uma sublist de disciplinas. Preciso criar algo como um "calendário semanal" para toda vez que eu selecionar um professor, eu mostrar as disciplinas dele no calendário semanal (pra eu saber o dia / duração da disciplina).

Pois bem, estou tentando usar o FullCalendar. Aqui meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>      
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendario</title>       
    <script src='calendario/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/lang/pt-br.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='calendario/fullcalendar.css'/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var dia = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0
        var mes = m < 10 ? '0' + m : '' + m;
        var ano = date.getFullYear();
        var data = ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;


        //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                center: 'title',
                left: '',
                right: ''
            },          

            height: 800,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',  

            views: {
                week: {
                    columnFormat: 'dddd'
                }
            },

            firstDay: 1,
            weekends: false,

            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Event1',
                    start: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia,
                    end: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia + 'T04:00'
                }
            ],

        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="teste">
        <div id="calendario"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podem ver, eu estou adicionando os `events` manualmente dentro do header. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso de forma dinâmica ? (Ou então, conselho de outra ferramente mais apropriada).

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [`renderEvent`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/):

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar(
    'renderEvent',
    {
      title: 'Novo evento',
      start: '2016-03-31',
    }
);
```

---

> Como usar datas no formato dd/mm/yyyy?

Nativamente, o FullCalendar só interpreta datas nos formatos permitidos pelo moment.js. Ou seja:

- string no formato [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (basicamente `2016-04-01` ou `2016-04-01T07:31:43Z`)
- unix offsets (milisegundos desde a Era Unix)
- Objetos `Date` nativos

Tem que fazer a conversão, uma forma conveniente seria:

```
moment('19/08/1949', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Tenho um evento que eu do `toggle` no menu, para ele abrir e mostra o submenu (efeito sanfona). Adicionando este trecho de código lá é pra funcionar de boa ?

Comment: Sim, pode colocar em qualquer lugar. Veja funcionando http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKwPXo

Comment: Excelente ! Última coisa, tem como fazer o plugin aceitar data no formato dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: o fi tem como fazer tudo, já que o projeto é opensource, mas nativamente ele só aceita alguns formatos específicos mesmo. editei minha resposta mostrando como fazer a conversão usando o moment.

Answer (score 1):

É só transformar em JSON
Dentro do Json vc tem que deixar os mesmos nomes "Start", "End", "Title", "Url" e assim por diante, feito isso é só chamar no seu sistema da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var link = $(location).attr('href');
  var url = link.split('/'); // Aqui estou dando split pra poder pegar a url, pois esse sistema está em 2 dominios

  $.getJSON("http://"+url[2]+"/tarefas/json", function( data ) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekends: false, // Desabilitando os finais de semana
        events: data // Aqui estou pegando o resultado do meu JSON
    });
  });
});
```